# How to analytically continue Schwinger functions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, wick-rotation, analyticity, wightman-fields

To get Wightman functions $W(t_1, \dots, t_{k-1})$ from Schwinger functions $S(\tau_1 = i t_1, \dots)$, we use analytical continuation.

But I don't think this is simply an issue of plugging $it_a$ for $\tau_a$. In fact, I think if we do this substitution, we will end up with the time-ordered Wightman function $G(t_1, \dots, t_{k-1})$ which coincides with $W$ only for $0 < t_1 < t_2 < \dots < t_{k-1}$.

My question is: what is the generic algorithm to compute $W_k$ from $S_k$ for any $k$?

For the special case of $k = 2$, this is trivial: assume $t > 0$, then
$$ G(t) = W(t) = \left< \Omega \right| \phi(0) \phi(t) \left| \Omega \right>. $$
Now take the conjugate:
$$ G^{*}(t) = \left< \Omega \right| \phi(t) \phi(0) \left| \Omega \right> = W(-t).$$
Therefore,
$$ W(-t) = G^{*}(t). $$

I wonder how this algorithm can be generalized to higher-order functions.

Comment: You keep the real parts of Euclidean time arguments in Schwinger functions ordered as you would like the operators in a Wightman function to be ordered. You then analytically continue by adding imaginary parts, keeping the real parts fixed. The imaginary parts will become the Lorentzian times. Finally, you take real parts to 0, while keeping their ordering fixed. The result in general is not a function but a distribution. We tried to write a review of these classic but sometimes forgotten facts in a recent paper https://inspirehep.net/literature/1856401.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk this is exactly what I was looking for! Why not make your comment into an answer so that I can upvote it?